# Detect sound is ended in THREE.PositionalAudio?

Tags: javascript, audio, three.js

I want to detect when sounds is ending, but all examples that i found not working.

```
// Create sound
var sound1 = new THREE.PositionalAudio( listener );
sound1.load( 'sounds/Example.ogg' );
sound1.setRefDistance( 30 );
sound1.autoplay = false;
sound1.setLoop(false);
mesh1.add( sound1 );

// Start sound
setTimeout(function() {
    sound1.play();
}, 2000);

// Try to detect end #1
sound1.onended = function() {
    console.log('sound1 ended #1');
};
// Try to detect end #1
sound1.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    console.log('sound1 ended #2');
});
```

**Live example:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMRoWQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Three.Audio` is wrapper around a buffer source audio object. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ddab1fda4fd1e21babf65aa454fc0fe15bfabc33/src/audio/Audio.js#L12

It looks like it overrides the onended event and binds it to its own function, so we just do the same:

```
sound1.source.onended = function() {
    console.log('sound1 ended');
    this.isPlaying = false; /* sets Three wrapper property correctly */
};
```

We set `isPlaying = false` because this is what [Three's Audio onended function does](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ddab1fda4fd1e21babf65aa454fc0fe15bfabc33/src/audio/Audio.js#L218), which we just overrode.

working pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoambE

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to detect onLoad / onReady sound event ?

Comment: That is a bit more complicated, and I can't find a good way to do it other than overriding one of Three.Audio's functions (done http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPzROz) I am going to file a bug report to see what the status on exposing some of these events are.

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8176 issue filed. If there's isn't already an easier solution, I will take a stab at a PR to expose these events in a easier way. I think audio in three is pretty new, as it's not even documented yet...

Answer (score 1):

I just had to solve this problem in 2020. I wasn't looking at the docs right at first, but it is correctly listed, it seems.

Similar to the previously correct answer, but a bit different now (that solution did not work for me):

```js
var sound1 = new THREE.PositionalAudio( listener );
sound1.onEnded = () => console.log("track ended")
```

Here's the appropriate docs: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/audio/Audio.onEnded

There's not much there, basically:

> .onEnded () : null
>
> Called automatically when playback finished.

Things that did *not* work for me:

```js
sound1.onEnded(() => {})
el.object3D.source.onended(() => {})
sound1.source.onended(() => {}); // previous answer
```

If you do this, you can intercept a call, but I don't think it's necessary anymore:

```js
  THREE.Audio.prototype.onEnded = function() {
      console.warn("arguments to onEnded!", arguments)
  };
```