# THREE.Audio - get currentTime and setting onEnded function

Tags: javascript, audio, three.js

In my Three.js app, I've worked a simple way for loading, playing and analysing audio, that works both on desktop and mobile. Must Use THREE.Audio, because HTML5 Audio Analyser doesn't work on mobile, THREE.AudioAnalyser instead yes.
Very happy except I can't find way to:

- get current time of audio playing
- set an onEnded function

Here the code:

```
function soundLoad() {
listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
audio = new THREE.Audio( listener );
audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader();
analyser = new THREE.AudioAnalyser( audio, 32 );
audioLoader.load( 'audio/01.mp3', function( buffer ) {
    audio.setBuffer( buffer );
    audio.setLoop( false );
    audio.setVolume( 1 );
    (function readyToGo() {
        console.log(audio.buffer.duration); // yes it works
        document.getElementById('btnPlay').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
           audio.play(); 
           setInterval(function(){
             console.log(audio.context.currentTime); // starts counting from the loading, not from the actual play
             console.log(audio.buffer.currentTime); // doesnt' work
           }, 10);
        }, false);
        // audio.onEnded = function() { console.log(‘end’);}; 
        // audio.buffer.onEnded = function() { console.log(‘end’);};
        // audio.source.onEnded = function() { console.log(‘end’);}; //none of them works
    })();
});}
```

Hopefully there's a solution for both issues, without having to create an actual ctx or other third parts. thanks!

Comment: this one example, doesn't work with me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323062/detect-sound-is-ended-in-three-positionalaudio/35497371#35497371 - source is undefined

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mugen87 hints, I've wrote simple lines that get to what I need - in the render function, so checked every frame:

Declaration

```
var audioPrevTime, audioCurrentTime, data;
```

In render function:

```
if (pause == 0){
    audioCurrentTime = audio.context.currentTime - audio.startTime + audioPrevTime;
    if (audioCurrentTime >= audio.buffer.duration){
        console.log('end song');
    }
    data = analyser.getAverageFrequency();
} else if (pause == 1){
    audioPrevTime = audioCurrentTime;
}
```

All in all these few lines enable to load, play, control and analyze sound for both desktop and mobile (on the devices I've tested so far so good).

Answer (score 0):

`three.js` does not expose Web Audio events, so it's no recommended to overwrite `AudioScheduledSourceNode.onended`. This can have unexpected side effects. If you need the current time of the audio, you have to calculate this value by yourself. Try this:

```
const currentTime = audio.context.currentTime - audio.startTime;
```

Comment: Thanks! About onEnded: three.js documentations says there's a method https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/audio/Audio.onEnded - is that of no use?

Comment: About currentTime: good, but what if I audio.pause(); then? audio.context.currentTime will keep on counting.

Comment: `Audio.onEnded()` is for internal use only. It does not make sense when the user calls it. It's only documented for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Well, when the audio pauses you have to store the value of `audio.context.currentTime` for that particular audio. Essentially, you have to implement the entire management code by yourself if you want to catch all edge cases.